# How can i set google admob size?

Tags: admob

I'm on integrating google admob to android.
Guard said that SMART_BANNER is the size that have full width of screen.
But when i used SMART_BANNER,it is not matches to screen width.
If you know about this method,please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

`<com.google.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" />`

Comment: Also take a look at the following link: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/